# Video not shown on HDMI screen

Tags: display, hdmi

When I connect HDMI cable from PC to HD TV, it duplicates everything on my PC screen to TV, except "video". When I play video, the video will be shown normally on PC screen but shown as blank screen (black color) on my TV while the sound of video still comes out from TV.

I have tried all media players (Windows Media Player, Real Player, GOM Player, etc.) but all results the same; blank screen.

I'm using Windows XP

What should I do.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with video overlays. Basically, when your computer is "drawing" a video, it doesn't draw it to screen in the same way that it draws everything else. (Like your windows.) Instead, the video frames get uploaded directly to your video card, with the instructions to draw them in a special place on the screen. This greatly helps with performance.

For some reason, your video card is drawing to your normal screen, but not the TV. As for how to fix it, I have no idea.

Adding some details about your video card and such may help you get an answer.

Comment: But I can play Youtube on PC & TV at the same time. Only the video files saved on my PC can't be displayed on TV.

Comment: That's because Youtube (or more specifically, Flash) displays the videos in a different way. AFAIK, Flash doesn't provide direct access to hardware video acceleration. Now that I think about it, it makes sense that the video would only be drawn on one screen with video acceleration. It's probably just a limitation of the technologies involved. When you're sharing screens, your video card just draws it to the first screen it can find. Switching to multiple-desktop mode allows you to pick which screen it should be drawn on.

Comment: I can play video on TV if I use extend mode (sending video from PC to play on secondary screen which is TV). That means my TV can accept video acceleration, doesn't it? But what I want is to duplicate everything on PC screen (including video) to show on TV as well.

Comment: Yes, your video card is running both the PC screen and TV screen, so it can do acceleration on either one. However, due to limitations in the card (or possibly the APIs), it can only do video acceleration for a window on one at a time. There's really no way around it, AFAIK. I don't think replacing your video card would even work. The only possible solution I can come up with involves VLC. VLC has a feature that allows you to clone a video to multiple windows. You could then put one window on each screen, but you would still have to be in multiple-desktop mode.

Comment: You are right. I tried using TV as primary screen and it could show video while the PC screen couldn't. It seems like my PC can only process video on one screen at a time.

Comment: Like I said, I believe that is a very common limitation. It may in fact be a limitation in Windows, in which case it affects *all* Windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

Your video player is using hardware video acceleration. Under this mode, most video cards can only draw to one screen at a time. When you're sharing screens between the PC and TV, your video card has to pick one to draw to, and just picks the first one.

If you configure your display settings for multiple-desktops, you should be able to drag the video player to the TV's screen. At this point, the video card won't need to draw the video to the PC's screen, and should draw it on the TV instead.

I don't know of any way to fix this besides that. It's a limitation of your video card. (And a pretty common one at that.) Theoretically, disabling hardware acceleration could fix the issue, but you ***really*** don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this issue. I was having the same trouble with HDMI as well as a WiDi connection - media players would show video on my laptop but not on the TV display. I use GOM player for everything. In the preferences menu, I changed my "Video Output" from "Overlay Mixer (Recommended)" to "(Default System Settings)" and video now shows up on both screens. (I also found that VLC player always shows up on both screens, but I just prefer GOM.) Hope this helps.